# Why are these PHP variables in the PDO prepare statement not binding?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple SQL statement where I am biding variables and it is not binding.  The values work when hard coding them in the update statement but do not work when I bind them:

```
if(isset($_GET["coachUpdate"])) {
    if ($pdoLink = \Database::GetInstance()->GetPDO()) {
        $updateQuerySQL = "UPDATE Registration SET Coach = :coach WHERE Reg = :reg";
        if ($updateQuery = $pdoLink->prepare($updateQuerySQL)) {
            $bindValues = "";

            $bindValues[":reg"] = $_GET["Reg"];
            $bindValues[":coach"] = $_GET["Coach"];

            if ($updateQuery->execute($bindValues)) {
                if ($query->rowCount()) {
                    echo $updateQuerySQL;
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Registration update query prep failed.<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because you have not formatted your code properly, the mighty PHP hammer wielding thor has decided this should be your fate

Comment: `var_dump($bindValues)` what does it contain?

Comment: You have not posted your real code because this will produce an error `$bindValues = "";

            $bindValues[":reg"] = $_GET["Reg"];`

Comment: What's wrong with: $bindValues = ""; $bindValues[":reg"] = $_GET["Reg"];

Comment: Going from a string to an array is not the problem. I see that it should be $bindValues = []; That way I am not going from a string to an array. I cbhanged that and it still is not binding